# Snowflake copy into not recognising timestamp

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Any suggestions on the below, i am trying to use copy into to move parquet files from S3 into snowflake table. Col1 is a timestamp and the rest are strings.

```
copy into table1 from
(select $1:col1, $1:col2, $1:col3
from @stage/path)
file_format = (format_name = parquet_format);
```

and getting the following error

> Failed to cast variant value "20050111 00:00:00" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ

I have tried

```
copy into table1 from
(select to_timestamp($1:col1, 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss'), $1:col2, $1:col3
from @stage/path)
file_format = (format_name = parquet_format);
```

but getting the error

> Error: too many arguments for function [TO_TIMESTAMP(GET(STAGE.$1, 'col1'), 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss')] expected 1, got 2 (line 130)

Any ideas

Comment: Try `select to_timestamp($1:col1::string, 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss')`

Comment: @GregPavlik can you post it as an answer? This is 2nd time I checked this question because I see it is not answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is this in this expression:

```
(select to_timestamp($1:col1, 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss')
```

This part: `$1:col1` is resolving to an object rather than a primitive data type. This is what's leading to the error message about getting 2 arguments instead of one.

Changing this part of the expression to `$1:col1::string` casts the expression as a primitive type - string or varchar. This is the type of parameter the `to_timestamp` function is expecting. The final statement should be:

```
copy into table1 from
(select to_timestamp($1:col1::string, 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss'), $1:col2, $1:col3
from @stage/path)
file_format = (format_name = parquet_format);
```